# SQL Server separate a column into some columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

The data looks like:

```
Measure   Value    Date  
--------------------------------
1         2.3      2016-01-01
1         2.5      2016-01-02
1         2.6      2016-01-03
2         1.2      2016-01-01
2         1.3      2016-01-02
2         1.4      2016-01-03
```

I want to make the Value column separated into 2 columns depending on the Measures

The final output should look like

```
Date          Value_Measure_1     Value_Measure_2
---------------------------------------------------------------------
2016-01-01    2.3                 1.2
2016-01-02    2.5                 1.3
2016-01-03    2.6                 1.4
```

The only way I can find out is self-join.

Is there any other method could do it better?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

If you have just 1 row per date per measure, you can do it this way:

```
select
  Date,
  max(case when Measure = 1 then value end) as Value_Measure_1
  max(case when Measure = 2 then value end) as Value_Measure_2
from
  yourtable
group by
  Date
```

Answer (score 1):

Use conditional aggregation :

```
SELECT t.date,
       MAX(CASE WHEN t.Measure = 1 THEN t.Value END) as val_meas_1,
       MAX(CASE WHEN t.Measure = 2 THEN t.Value END) as val_meas_2
FROM YourTable t
GROUP BY t.date
```

Answer (score 0):

I'll suggest you to use the pivot function with some T-SQL.